# Predefine a selectMultipleSideBySide in TS

Tags: typoscript, typo3-9.x

My problem is quite simple but I could not find anything on the Internet. I want to default my "User" field to all users.

I found how to set a default field with the TSConfig :

```
TCAdefaults {
  tx_ewillalerte_domain_model_alerte {
    utilisateur = 1,2,3
  }
}
```

In the example above, users with ids 1, 2 and 3 are set as default when I create a record. However, I would like them all to be, but there are many and it is possible that a new user appears or disappears (the number of users is not fixed).

I tried `utilisateur = all` and `utilisateur = *` so if anyone knows how to do it, I'm interested!

Comment: AFAIK, there's no wildcard option to set defaults, for such purposes I use, hooks and scheduler tasks to modify records after insert/update.

Comment: How do you do that?

Comment: This is a broad topic (doesn't qualify for the single answer at SO) and depends on the used TYPO3 version, so the best option is googling for "*TYPO3 hooks*". [Here are docs for hooks](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/Hooks/Hooks/Index.html) In a very similar case I used last time `processDatamap_postProcessFieldArray` and I think you should go in this direction. Creating Scheduler's task is also [described in the official docs](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-scheduler/master/en-us//DevelopersGuide/CreatingTasks/Index.html).